# Cannot install Windows Server 2003 - setup reports missing file (agjh1tpp.sys)

Tags: windows-server-2003, installation

I'm trying to upgrade a Windows 2000 Server machine to Windows 2003 Server. When I run the installer, it gets near the end of the "copying files" stage, and then complains that a file "agjh1tpp.sys" is missing.

There are no google hits whatsoever for that file name, so I have no idea what it is.

I have the option to skip this file and continue, but if I do so, then shortly after that it reboots the machine, and immediately complains about this file being missing. (Luckily I can still boot into Windows 2000 at this stage).

I've used several different ISO images from MSDN (Standard, Professional, R2, etc.), and also a Windows 2003 Server installation CD, and the same problem occurs each time.

WTF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.sys` are device drivers usually.  Check and see if there's some third-party drivers you need for the installer to finish (maybe RAID or SCSI cards?)

It does sound like some hardware is holding up the upgrade.  Take a look at [DevCon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272) to see if you can either find the right drivers or disable the hardware.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If I have a disk drive of some sort that needs a device driver, then wouldn't it already be on the machine? Why would it suddenly complain about it being missing because I'm upgrading the OS?

Comment: If it *were* a driver for some disk drive that I'm no longer using, is there some way I could persuade the installer that it's not required? It simply refuses to go on without this file...

Comment: Hmmm... I went to the Device Manager, and there are two PCI devices that have no driver (they show up as a yellow triangle/question mark). I tried "un-installing" these two, but after a reboot, the "found new hardware" wizard comes up and tries (and fails) to find a driver. They get put back in the list, in the same state as before. So I'm inclined to think you're onto something. Trouble is, how I can I get rid of them?

Comment: So, I remembered some of the history of this PC, and that it was bought as a Windows XP box which I flattened when I installed Windows Server 2000. Thus some of the drivers that came with it will have been lost in the process. Luckily it's a Dell, so I was able to use the service tag to go download all the original drivers. Having installed all but one, I've now only got one "problem" PCI device, and the Windows 2003 Server setup now complains about a different file - which makes me thing the first file it complained about is now present. Partial success! However...

Comment: ... I was unable to install one of the drivers (which I think is for the media card reader) because the installer says it's Windows XP only. This leaves me with no way to get that remaining driver in place. I did try disconnecting the cable to the card reader, but that didn't seem to help (I had hoped it would forget it ever existed).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this type of error many times (with client OS installs), and it usually means you have a faulty memory module.

Do you have any diagnostic software bundled with the server that you can run?